# DRF API schema TypeError: view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi

I was going through the docs on DRF [schema](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/) and installed the packages pyyaml and uritemplate. I added the urls to my urls.py file. Later I pip installed coreapi following [this](https://youtu.be/-nuobfiU49Q?t=642) tutorial

```
urlpattern = [
...
   path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='BlogAPI')), 
   path('openapi', get_schema_view(
        title="Your Project",
        description="API for all things …",
        version="1.0.0"
    ), name='openapi-schema'),
```

I shows me the following error on login to the url

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/

Django Version: 3.1.6
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'GisApplication.apps.GisapplicationConfig',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'rest_framework',
 'storages',
 'django.contrib.gis']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\views.py", line 48, in handle_exception
    return super().handle_exception(exc)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\views.py", line 37, in get
    schema = self.schema_generator.get_schema(request, self.public)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\coreapi.py", line 156, in get_schema
    links = self.get_links(None if public else request)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\coreapi.py", line 143, in get_links
    link = view.schema.get_link(path, method, base_url=self.url)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\coreapi.py", line 369, in get_link
    fields += self.get_filter_fields(path, method)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\schemas\coreapi.py", line 526, in get_filter_fields
    fields += filter_backend().get_schema_fields(self.view)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /docs/
Exception Value: view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

None of the previous answers with same error helped as it is not originating from my views. What might be the problem?

Comment: Please, provide the code for `include_docs_urls`.

Comment: it is provided by django itself `from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls`

Comment: `url` is in your app's folder or in your project's folder? It wasn't supposed to be `urlpatterns`?

Comment: sorry, typo in the question. it is indeed urlpattern. also, url is in the apps folder. i tried putting in the project folder, but did not work